Neovim Clangd LSP rename symbol doesn't change project-wide
I am using Neovim through the NVChad distribution, with the clangd language server. When I try to use the rename symbol feature, it does not rename that symbol across my entire project - just any open files (and if there are too many open, not even all open files).
How can I circumvent this to make the rename happen project-wide? It would make it a lot more convenient for refactoring. For anyone who wants my specific Neovim config, you can see it in my config repository here

Does your project have a compile_commands.json file set up as described at https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup ?

Using bear to generate this file worked for me. Thank you!

Like @HighCommander4 suggested in the comments, setting up a compile_commands.json fixed this issue.

Adding also why this fixes the problem: having a compile_commands.json file gives clangd a list of source files in the project, allowing clangd to build an index for the project that cross-references information across all indexed files. Features such as rename rely on the index to find all occurrences of a symbol in the project.
